# Deep attestation of VM's

Tags: cloud-computing, trusted-computing, trusted-boot

Hypervisors like Xen have virtual TPM ([vTPM](http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Virtual_Trusted_Platform_Module_(vTPM))) support. In cloud environments, are there any implementations where such vTPM's are being used during remote attestation in addition to the host TPM based attestation in practice? What are the possible advantages/drawbacks of using vTPM's?

Answer (score 1):

There is a very helpful document on this from [IBM](http://www.kiskeya.net/ramon/work/pubs/security06.pdf) that can enlighten you on your query.

> It is necessary to enable remote
>   parties that have established trust in the initial environment
>   to also establish trust in the vTPM environment at
>   a later point in time.
>   For example, the strong binding of TPM credentials
>   to those of the hardware platform is important to challenging
>   parties during remote attestation. The challenger
>   must follow the trust chain from the target platform’s
>   hardware TPM through a virtual TPM and into the runtime
>   environment of the associated virtual machine.

Pay special attention to page 6.